# Switch Activity sliently while app is in background

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an Activity A which is listening to some websocket message, when it receive certain message, it will navigate to Activity B by `startActivity()`.

Things works fine when App is on foreground, but when it's on background, the `startActivity()` will cause the App bring to front automatically.

> How can I "sliently" startActivity() in background without bringing
>   the app to foreground?

Comment: 'Activity' is for Displaying UI to user, in this case you may use 'Service' or 'IntentService' perform required task, and when user clicks on application depending on some variable you can open required 'Activity'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  What you can do is set a flag, then in onResume call startActivity for the next activity if the flag is set.

Or use fragments instead of activities.

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly possible to do so, However you can try something like minimizing the app as soon as the activity gets started.

In the `onCreate` method of your activity use the following statement:

```
YourActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Of course you will need to use some flags and extras to prevent it from being minimized in other cases too.

Answer (score 1):

as @Gabe said, You can do this by setting a flag, same as we do open login or main activity by checking user object in SharedPreference.

```
if(SharedPreference Message count > 0){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, YourChattingActivity.class));
        }
```

Also you will need to set message count in SharedPreference.

Answer (score 1):

Using below link you are able to achieve what you want:
[Here is the solution to check activity status and handle according to that.](http://timnew.me/blog/2013/12/19/start-acitivity-in-background-on-android-4-4-kitkat/)